# Guardar datos de un formulario que contiene también un select multiple con ajax

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Necesito guardar los datos de un formulario que contiene a su vez un select multiple, el problema es que no me deja guardar los datos en la base de datos

Este es mi formulario

```
  <form class="form-horizontal" id="frmAsociacion" method="post">      
                <div class="form-group" >
                        <label for="selectPrograma" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Programa: </label>
                                <div class="col-sm-8"><select name="selectPrograma" id="selectPrograma" class="form-control" onChange="cargarA(this.value)" >
                                    <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
                                </select></div>

                    </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group" >
            <label for="selectAsignatura" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Asignatura: </label>
              <div class="col-sm-8"><select name="selectAsignatura" id="selectAsignatura" class="form-control" >
                <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
              </select></div>

        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-group" >
               <label for="selectDocente" class=" col-sm-1 control-label">Grupos: </label>
              <div class="col-sm-8"><select name="grupos[]" id="multi" cols="50" rows="3" class="form-control1 chosen" multiple data-live-search="true" required>

        <?php

        while($a=mysqli_fetch_assoc($grupos)){?>
            <option value="<?php echo $a['id_grupo'];?>"><?php echo $a['numero_grupo'];?></option>
            <?php
        }


        ?>

        </select></div>
        </div>

                    <br>
                    <br>    
                        <div class="col-sm-8"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
               <button class="btn btn-success " name="Asociar" onclick="asociarGrupo();" type="submit" id="ver-perfil">Asociar</button>


            </div>   
             <br><br><br>  
             <div class="clearfix"> </div>

                    </form>
```

Y esta es la función asociarGrupo()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          function asociarGrupo(){
              var url="agregarGrupoAsignatura.php";

              var x=document.getElementById("multi");

              var grupos=[];

  for (var i = 0; i < x.options.length; i++) {
     if(x.options[i].selected ==true){
         grupos.push(x.options[i].value);

      }
  }

             alert([{grupos:grupos}]);
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:url,
            data:{array:[{x:grupos}]},
            success: function(datos){

                 $('#contenido').html(datos);

            }
        });

    }</script>
```

Y por ultimo el url asociarGrupoAsignatura

```
    <?php
session_start();
 include_once('conexion.php');
$user=$_SESSION['username'];

$cod_asignatura = $_POST["selectAsignatura"];
$data = json_encode($_POST["array"]);
$array=json_decode($data);


$grupos=array_values($array[0]->x);

$no_guardados=array("");




    for($j=0;$j<count($grupos);$j++){

            $consultar="SELECT g.numero_grupo numero_grupo FROM grupo g WHERE g.id_grupo = '$grupos[j]' ";

            $r=mysqli_num_rows (ConsultarGrupo($consultar));


            if($r==0){
                $agregar="INSERT INTO asignatura_grupo(id_asignatura,id_grupo) VALUES('$cod_asignatura','$grupos[$j]')";
                asociarGrupo($agregar);
            }

    }




function asociarGrupo($agregar){
return mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conexion'],$agregar);

}

function ConsultarGrupo($consultar){
    return mysqli_query($GLOBALS['conexion'],$consultar);
}
?>
```

En general lo unico que quiero es que me pueda guardar en la base de datos el Id de la asignatura con el nombre del grupo a los que pertenece, si alguien sabe como realizarlo seria de gran ayuda

Comment: Pero ¿da algún error o algo? ¿Probaste que los datos estén llegando bien al servidor ? Si fuera tú no usaría `json_decode` para manipular los datos, y si lo usas debes revisar lo que esa función está haciendo con tus datos, ya que por lo general le agrega slahes a los datos y cosas así. Revisa los datos con los que estás trabajando porque cualquier caracter raro hará que falle el código. Además, no tienes ningún control de errores en tus funciones, lo cual es un error de concepción, valga la redundancia.

Comment: Que me recomienda utilizar, necesito urgente guardar esos datos en la base de datos

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar lo que está llegando al servidor, haciendo un `var_dump($_POST);`?  Ni siquiera se sabe si los datos están llegando bien ni como llegan organizados. Luego, no es necesario convertirlos a JSON para trabajar con ellos en el servidor.